# Some mathjax in an old post is broken due to curly brackets expressions

Tags: bug, mathjax, editing

I found that in this old post [Colimit of topological groups (again)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5297/113448) some mathjax is broken due to wierd brackets notation. $\left\\{...\right\\}$`\left\\{...\right\\}` is written instead of $\left\{...\right\}$`\left\{...\right\}`. And it produces 'Missing \left or extra \right' error for me.

I tried editing it myself, but I can't submit an edit because it constitutes less than six  characters. So, I decided to write about this on meta. I think it would be right if somebody with higher privileges would edit it instead of me.

Moreover, what concerns me is that, such mathjax probably was rendering correctly in the past. I don't know if it was a common practice to format curly braces like this in the past. But, if so, there can be other old posts with such formatting errors.

Comment: I've fixed it; it was an issue with older implementations.

Comment: This seems to be less a bug and more a deprecated feature.  But I'm in favor of keeping an eye out for similar problems in very old posts.

Comment: @hardmath: It's actually the result of a fix. It used to be that the backslash acted as an escape character, even within the MathJax environment (it still messes up here in the comments, for example, if I don't put a space after the second backslash...), so you had to type `\\ ` in order to alert it that you really did mean a backslash. It got fixed, but older posts still have the `\\ ` format.

Comment: @hardmath I understand that this is not really software bag in a pure sense. But this is still a reproducible error in some sense, so I decided that a bug tag would draw intended attention. If this bothers you, I can remove this tag or change it to something more appropriate which you may suggest .

Comment: Google seems to find Math.SE posts with character string '\\{' efficiently, but the handful of cases I've looked at so far are benign, such as old comments or titles whose sense is clear.

Comment: I think the error only happens then '\\{' is preceeded by '\left'.